# Por que razão usar unless no Laravel, ao invés de uma negação no if?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Acho o `Laravel` um framework interessante. As funcionalidades das view são excelentes, quanto à simplificação da sintaxe de um `foreach` ou `if`por exemplo.

Mas ainda uma coisa que não entendi é: Para que o `unless`?

Por que usar o `@unless` se simplesmente pode fazer uma `@if(! $expressao)`?

Quais são os benefícios de o Blade aceitar um `@unless`?

Existe algum caso que é mais benéfico usá-lo do que um `@if` com negação?

Exemplo:

```
 @unless(Auth::user()->admin)
     <div>Você não é administrador</div>
 @endunless

 {{-- aqui é menos código, não acham? --}}
 @if(!Auth::user()->admin)
     <div>Você não é administrador</div>
 @endif
```

Comment: sintax suggar somente =D O Laravel é cheio disso

Comment: Sinceramente, pra mim, não facilitou a leitura.
Houve uma substituição de um operador conhecido (!) por um método (unless) menos comum.
Na minha opinião, uma função tem que trazer mais do que somente melhor "leitura", deveria trazer benefícios de performance (lambda, por exemplo), simplificar as declarações reduzindo a quantidade de código (foreach, warn...) e por aí vai.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não programo em PHP, conheço o `unless` por programar em Ruby.

Como você já deve ter notado:

> ***unless* é a inversão do *if***, então em vez de você fazer um *if* sobre uma condição negada, se fizer mais sentido para a legibilidade do código, você faz um *unless* sobre a condição natural, sem precisar negá-la.

Vamos ler o seu primeiro exemplo:

> **A menos que** você seja um administrador, "você não é administrador".

Vamos ler o seu segundo exemplo:

> **Se** você **não** for um administrador, "você não é administrador".

É apenas uma questão de semântica, e se você está acostumado com o uso do comando, pode achar que em alguns casos a leitura do código soa melhor com *unless* do que com *if not*.

Todavia o código com *unless* pode ficar difícil de ler se você abusar dele, como usá-lo para testar uma condição negada (ele já é a negação da condição!) ou usá-lo em conjunto com *else*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Apesar de não ser sobre Laravel, o tema abordado representa muito bem o cenário que o `unless` é usado. +1